# Ограничение на скорость скачивания файла

Tags: java

Скачиваю файл по ссылке таким образом:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, FileNotFoundException {
    URL url  = new URL("http://localhost:8092/img/universe.jpg");

    try (InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
         FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("/home/sergei/hello.jpg")) {
        byte buffer[] = new byte[128];
        while (inputStream.read(buffer) != -1) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Не могу придумать как сделать ограничение на скорость скачивания... Может быть существуют стандартные механизмы или надо делать велосипед ?

Comment: [ссылка](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2011/03/tenfold-increase-in-server-throughput.html)

Comment: можно взять Guava [RateLimiter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то делал с классом [RateLimiter](https://guava.dev/releases/20.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html). Простейший пример будет выглядеть так:

```
final RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(5000.0); // макс. 5кБ в сек.
void submitPacket(byte[] packet) {
    rateLimiter.acquire(packet.length);
    networkService.send(packet);
}
```